# Mq_receive seemingly crashing program without any error

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I'm trying out some multi-threading using a message queue and ran into a block with mq_receive, which is causing crashes that don't report anything back. The idea is that I have some requests coming in from another process via a message queue that will need some data extracted. Here is the relevant code for the processing program that I wrote:

All of this is in a file called request.c

```
mqd_t global_queue; // Global queue for receiving all requests, since message queues are thread-safe
pthread_t tArr[10];
...
...
int main()
{
   global_queue = mq_open("/queue_name", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777, NULL);
   for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
   {
      pthread_create(&tArr[k], NULL, process, NULL);
   }
}
```

And the code for the process function:

```
// Process an indefinite amount of requests
while (1) 
{
   struct mq_attr chars;
   mq_getattr(global_queue, chars);
   printf("getarr passed");
   char recBuf[chars.mq_msgsize];
   unsigned int prio = 0;
   int errNo;
   printf("Before recv");
   errNo = mq_receive(queue, recBuf, chars.mq_msgsize, &prio);
   if (errNo < 0)
   {
      perror("mq_receive");
   }
   printf("After recv");
}
```

Normally, I would expect to see an error is mq_receive failed via perror, but that does not seem to happen. The "Before recv" print goes through and the program appears to terminate since neither the perror message nor the "After recv" messages are printed. I was under the impression that mq_receive is a blocking call and should block if there are no queue entries; however, this behavior seems to be consistent when I have queue data and when the queue is empty. Removing the mq_receive call causes the infinite loop to progress and print everything as normal, so it seems like the mq_receive call is the problem.

Comment: This is going to be very hard to even guess with that little context or code. Please try to create a [mre] to show us. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: Note that before exiting your program (i.e. returning from main), you have to ensure that no other thread is running. One way to do this is by joining with all of the threads you've created.

Comment: Your call to `mq_getattr` should have given you a compiler warning and will definitely not work. The second parameter is supposed to be a pointer.